# Subquery returned more than one value, not permitted error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data from one table to another where the records match on a foreign key. I am using SSMS. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO competitor_info (p21_part_number)
    SELECT inv_mast.item_id
    FROM inv_mast 
    WHERE inv_mast.upc_code = 
            (SELECT item_info.UPC
            FROM item_info)
```

I am getting the following error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `IN`:

```
WHERE inv_mast.upc_code IN 
        (SELECT item_info.UPC
        FROM item_info)
```

I prefer `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM item_info.UPC WHERE UPC.item_info = inv_mast.upc_code)
```

This often has better performance, particularly with the right indexes.